# Record is updated successfully but "saveRecord" callback of "force:recordData" is invoked with response.state as ERROR

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

1. I have a lightning action on Contact object built using Aura component.
2. This component uses Lightning Data Service (`force:recordData`) to update a specific field on Contact record.
3. When the Contact record is updated, after update trigger on Contact object runs and creates new record and deletes current record.

Everything is working fine but the `saveRecord` of `force:recordData` callback is always receiving response.state as ERROR with errorMessage as "The requested resource does not exist."

The record on which `saveRecord` is invoked, is ultimately deleted because of the trigger on that object.I am not sure if I am misusing `saveRecord` method of `force:recordData` LDS.

Here is the sample code:

**CreateNewRecordAndDeleteCurrentRecord.cmp**:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData   aura:id="recordHandler"
                        fields="['Id','CreateNewRecordAndDeleteThisRecord__c']"
                        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                        targetRecord="{!v.record}"
                        targetFields ="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                        mode="EDIT" />
    <lightning:button label="Confirm" onclick="{!c.updateRecord}" variant="brand"/>        

</aura:component>
```

**CreateNewRecordAndDeleteCurrentRecordController.js**:

```
({
    updateRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.simpleRecord.CreateNewRecordAndDeleteThisRecord__c",true); 
        component.find("recordHandler").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(response) {
            if (component.isValid() && response.state == "SUCCESS") {
            } else if (response.state == "ERROR") {
                //It is always entering here.
            }
        }));
    }

})
```

**ContactTrigger.trigger**:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after update){
    List<Contact> consToInsert = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> consToDelete = new List<Contact>();
    for(Contact conObj: Trigger.new){
        if(conObj.CreateNewRecordAndDeleteThisRecord__c == true){
            Contact newConObj = new Contact();
            newConObj.LastName = conObj.LastName + '_New';
            newConObj.FirstName = conObj.FirstName + '_New';
            newConObj.Email = conObj.Email;
            newConObj.Phone = conObj.Phone;
            consToInsert.add(newConObj);
            consToDelete.add(conObj);
        }

    }
    insert consToInsert;
    delete consToDelete;
}
```

Comment: Not sure the logic behind cloning and deleting a updated record, same problem would happen when you update a record from standard UI, it would redirect to a deleted record. Could you add some more background on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Raul Thanks for taking a look. I will add more details tomorrow once I am at my desk. Thanks!